# Short postion - Futures contract

Tags: futures

Assuming that an investor holds his short position until maturity and that he cannot close out his position. Will a seller that doesn't own the underlying ever enter into such a position?

Comment: Well the answer is "yes" and for a variety of reasons but I'm guessing there's more to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Sure - some possible reasons:

- hedging (maybe they are a *producer* of the underlying but don't actually hold a financial position
- speculation - they have a reason to think that the price of the underlying will fall
- spread trading - maybe they are trading the price of one underlying versus the price of another

I'm sure there are other possible scenarios as well.